# Strange error when seeding Mysql database with Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-seeding

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and I'm using a database seeder to seed my local mysql database while developing. Here's some code from the seeder:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    $products = factory(App\Product::class, 100)->create();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        // Assign some reviews to each product
        $reviews = factory(App\ProductReview::class, rand(0, 10))->make();
        $product->reviews()->saveMany($reviews);
    }
}
```

The seeder works as expected most of the time, but randomly while seeding I will get an error about an invalid datetime format for a certain column. I can not figure out what would be causing this, especially since the issue only appears about 20% of the time the seeder is run. Also, based on the error, I don't actually see any issues with the datetime format, so I'm not sure what's going on.

It also doesn't seem to be limited to just the reviews, other times I will see the error while the seeder is trying to create a product. I will paste the full error trace below. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction here as to what would be causing this.

```
[2018-05-03 15:51:14] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2008-03-09 02:18:48' for column 'created_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `product_reviews` (`product_id`, `order_id`, `name`, `email`, `location`, `rating`, `text`, `title`, `status`, `is_manually_verified`, `manual_verification_note`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (41, , Jaleel Corkery, uschimmel@example.net, Maeganhaven, Vermont, 1, Incidunt earum inventore facere eum. Repudiandae ipsam similique laboriosam et illum autem. Exercitationem rerum expedita est iste. Enim necessitatibus eaque delectus incidunt ullam inventore., Sed est qui vero., approved, 0, , 2008-03-09 02:18:48, 2018-05-03 15:51:14)) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 22007): SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2008-03-09 02:18:48' for column 'created_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `product_reviews` (`product_id`, `order_id`, `name`, `email`, `location`, `rating`, `text`, `title`, `status`, `is_manually_verified`, `manual_verification_note`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (41, , Jaleel Corkery, uschimmel@example.net, Maeganhaven, Vermont, 1, Incidunt earum inventore facere eum. Repudiandae ipsam similique laboriosam et illum autem. Exercitationem rerum expedita est iste. Enim necessitatibus eaque delectus incidunt ullam inventore., Sed est qui vero., approved, 0, , 2008-03-09 02:18:48, 2018-05-03 15:51:14)) at /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664, PDOException(code: 22007): SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2008-03-09 02:18:48' for column 'created_at' at row 1 at /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(624): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into `pr...', Array, Object(Closure))
#1 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(459): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('insert into `pr...', Array, Object(Closure))
#2 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(411): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->statement('insert into `pr...', Array)
#3 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/Processor.php(32): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->insert('insert into `pr...', Array)
#4 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2349): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Processors\\Processor->processInsertGetId(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder), 'insert into `pr...', Array, 'id')
#5 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1285): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->insertGetId(Array, 'id')
#6 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(726): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->__call('insertGetId', Array)
#7 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(691): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->insertAndSetId(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder), Array)
#8 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(554): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->performInsert(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder))
#9 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php(250): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->save()
#10 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php(262): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\HasOneOrMany->save(Object(App\\ProductReview))
#11 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php(53): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\HasOneOrMany->saveMany(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection))
#12 [internal function]: DatabaseSeeder->run()
#13 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#15 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#16 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#17 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php(122): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#18 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeedCommand.php(63): Illuminate\\Database\\Seeder->__invoke()
#19 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php(122): Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Seeds\\SeedCommand->Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Seeds\\{closure}()
#20 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeedCommand.php(64): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model::unguarded(Object(Closure))
#21 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Seeds\\SeedCommand->handle()
#22 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#23 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#24 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#25 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#26 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#27 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(252): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#28 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#29 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(198): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#30 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/RefreshCommand.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->call('db:seed', Array)
#31 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/RefreshCommand.php(68): Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\RefreshCommand->runSeeder(NULL)
#32 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\RefreshCommand->handle()
#33 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#34 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#35 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#36 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#37 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#38 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(252): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#39 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#40 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(865): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#41 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(241): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\RefreshCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#42 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(143): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#43 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(88): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#44 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#45 /Users/me/dev/corp/platform/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#46 {main}
"}
```

Comment: If you try to run the command directly in your MySQL instance, do you get the error or does it work fine? (ps. which MySQL version are you using?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a weird issue.

`2008-03-09 02:18:48`

"The date/time looks valid, but it's actually between 2 and 3 AM on the early Sunday morning where time leaps forward from 2 to 3 AM. So, any time between 2 and 3 AM doesn't exist"

Converting the date/time to the right timezone can solve this issue.

In file: `config/app.php`

`'timezone' => 'UTC', //change UTC to your time zone, eg: 'America/Havana'`

Reference: https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/issues/1078

Comment: That is amazing. Thanks.